# ArangoDB Foxx pathParam is undefined

Tags: arangodb, foxx

Made a new Foxx app with the Web UI and added the following route:

```js
controller.get('/names/:name', function (request, response) {
  var name = request.params('name');

  response.json(db._query(
    "FOR x IN collection"+
      " FILTER x.name == " + name +
      " RETURN x"
    ).toArray());
})
.pathParam('name', { // line 112
  description: 'A name value to search for',
  type: 'String'
})
.errorResponse(ArangoError, 404, 'Data not found');
```

Which gives an error pointing to line 112 and prevents the app from running:

[image: http://puu.sh/kEx6h/5641b92739.png]

This runs fine if the `.pathParam` function is removed.

How can I fix this/what am I doing wrong? I'm using a fresh install with version 2.6.9 (latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the `type` sub-attribute in .pathParam()'s second parameter was changed in version 2.5 to use joi. So it needs to be changed to:

```
.pathParam('name', { // line 112
  description: 'A name value to search for',
  type: joi.string() // this line needs changing
})
```

Apart from that, you will need to `require` joi in the controller beforehand, i.e.

```
var joi = require('joi');
```

That tutorial is indeed out of date and needs fixing.

Comment: Great! I had another look at the tutorial and noticed incorrect syntax on page 10: `.pathParam('id', .pathParam('id', firstCollectio...`

Comment: should also be fixed by now

Answer (score 0):

So, according to the latest [controller docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/Develop/Controller.html), it seems the use of joi is now required.

Reason for the error was, I was following the [Foxx tutorial](https://www.arangodb.com/tutorial-foxx/#execute-query) which doesn't use joi.